# pass value selected in angularjs and web api

Tags: angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api

I have a option input that list data in html form in mvc application:

```
<div ng-app="RolesAp">
<div ng-controller="RolesController">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="post-content">
                <select ng-model="c.Title" ng-click="SendData(c)" ng-options="c.Title for c in Roles" id="ddlCategory"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

with controller :

```
GetRls();
function GetRls() {
    RolesService.GetRls()
        .success(function (Rls) {
            $scope.Roles = Rls;
            console.log($scope.Roles);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' +      error.message;
             console.log($scope.status);
         });
 }


  RolesAp.factory('RolesService', ['$http', function ($http) {
var RolesService = {};
RolesService.GetRls = function () {
    return $http.get('/api/Process/Get');
};
return RolesService;
  }]);
```

How pas selected value to another form with web api?

thanks.